# Rotate object as full screen

Tags: android

i'm stuck with an object rotation. i'm using `MpAndroidChart` library to create some graphs. i must show that graphs with fullscreen but i couldn't. is there any solution to do this ?

Tried this code but that didn't work.

```
                        BarChart barChart = new BarChart(getActivity());
                        barChart.setRotation(90);
                        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

                        BarChart.LayoutParams params = new BarChart.LayoutParams(metrics.heightPixels, metrics.widthPixels);
                        barChart.setLayoutParams(params);
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels);
                        rlChart.setLayoutParams(params2);
                        rlChart.addView(barChart);
```

in my code, i set width to height and height to width.

**Edit:** i'm trying to show the graphs inside `AlertDialog` and also my screen is not an `Activity`, it's `Fragment`

Comment: you could just request portrait orientation

Comment: Thanks for advice, i will try this.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko tried your solution but it gives `android.view.WindowLeaked` error.

Comment: it means that you did something wrong

Comment: you probably need to manually handle configuration changes (rotation)

Comment: i'm searching for any solution to your solution